# How to give multiple values to a single key using a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, cgi, berkeley-db, bsddb

I have a html form which has `Firstname`, `LastName`, `Age` and `Gender` and a `ADD` button. 
I enter the data into the form and that gets into the Berkeelys db. What my code does is it prints only the last values. I want that it should show all the values related to particular key

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import bsddb
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print "Content-type:text/html\n"
Fname = form.getvalue('firstname', '')
Lname = form.getvalue('lastname', '')
Age = form.getvalue('age', 0)
Gender = form.getvalue('gender', '')

#print Fname, Lname, Age 

db = bsddb.hashopen("/home/neeraj/public_html/database/mydb.db","w")
db['FirstName'] = Fname  
db['LastName'] = Lname
db['Age'] = Age 
db['Gender'] = Gender
db.close()
db = bsddb.hashopen("/home/neeraj/public_html/database/mydb.db","r")
#db = bsddb.hashopen("/home/neeraj/public_html/database/mydb.db")
print db['FirstName'], db['LastName'], db['Age'], db['Gender']
db.close()
print db
```

Comment: Avoid using [`bsddb`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bsddb.html) module, since it is deprecated. If you want a `dict`-like interface to a DB then use the [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module. Also: if you want to save more than a single object as a value then use a `list` as value and `append` the values when you insert them.

Comment: can i have more records objects stored in a db ?

Comment: What is a record object? You never defined it. Also, what do you mean by "db"? Do you mean a database handled by `shelve`? A database in general?

Comment: db means database. Now i am inserting a data into this database. i have stored let say 5 records with their Firstname, Lastname, Age and gender as a data. I have such 5 records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an SQL database instead of the `dict`-based interface, since SQL databases already handle multiple tuples in a table.

Anyway, if you want to have a `dict` interface you can use the `shelve` module (`bsddb` is deprecated, so you should avoid it) and save each value in a `list`:

```
import shelve

COLUMNS = ('FirstName', 'LastName', 'Age', 'Sex')

the_db = shelve.open('test.db', writeback=True)
for col_name in COLUMNS:
    if col_name not in the_db:
        the_db[col_name] = []

records = [
    ('John', 'Deer', 20, 'M'),
    ('Ada', 'Lovelace', 23, 'F'),
]

for record in records:
    for col_name, value in zip(COLUMNS, record):
        the_db[col_name].append(value)

the_db.close()

the_db = shelve.open('test.db')

for record in zip(*(the_db[col_name] for col_name in COLUMNS)):
    print(record)

the_db.close()
```

The above code outputs:

```
('John', 'Deer', 20, 'M')       
('Ada', 'Lovelace', 23, 'F')
```

---

If you want to use an SQL database you could use the `sqlite3` module.
For example:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE people (
    FirstName text,
    LastName text,
    Age int,
    Sex text
    )''')

cursor.execute('''
INSERT INTO people values ('John', 'Deer', 20, 'M')''')

cursor.execute('''
INSERT INTO people values ('Ada', 'Lovelace', 23, 'F')''')

conn.commit()

for record in cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM people'''):
    print(record)
```

The above code outputs:

```
(u'John', u'Deer', 20, u'M')
(u'Ada', u'Lovelace', 23, u'F')
```

(Note the `u'...'` simply means that the strings are unicode, it doesn't change their value)

However this code has some problems (e.g. try to run it twice...), but if you want to follow this path then you **must** learn SQL first, so go ahead and stufy it (there are a lot of online tutorials. For example `w3schools` ones).

Comment: i have not been into the shelve module. although i need that same working using Berkelys db module. n i appreciate your code written.

Answer (score 1):

The correct method to associate multiple values to a single key is to pack a list or dictionary value using for instance "json.dumps".

Here is an exemple:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from json import dumps
from json import loads
import bsddb

# write
users = bsddb.hashopen("users.db","w")
primarykey = 'amz'
users[primarykey] = dumps(dict(username="amz", age=30, bio="craftsman"))
users.close()

# read

users = bsddb.hashopen("users.db","r")

for key in users.keys():
    print loads(users[key])

users.close()
```

This is the basic pattern to be used with bsddb and is applicable to other key/value dbs like leveldb.

**Extra:**

Given the fact that bsddb hashmap keys are ordered lexicographically (ie. like python 2 strings) you can build hashmaps with keys having a predicatable order saving you the trouble of going through all the table.

To put that feature to good use you have to build useful keys. Again you need a packing function that translates python sort order to lexigraphic order (ie. `11 > 2` but `"11" < "2"`) . Here is an exemple such packing function:

```
def pack(*values):
    def __pack(value):
        if type(value) is int:
            return '1' + struct.pack('>q', value)
        elif type(value) is str:
            return '2' + struct.pack('>q', len(value)) + value
        else:
            data = dumps(value, encoding='utf-8')
            return '3' + struct.pack('>q', len(data)) + data
    return ''.join(map(__pack, values))
```

This is a kind of naive, you could go the extra mile and support `float` and better pack `int` to save space.

For instance, given the simplified schema `User(username, age)` you can build another hashmap we call `age_index` with which you can easily retrieve every user at
 age of 30. The hashmap can look like the following:

```
   key    | value
 -----------------
  29  tom |   X
  30  amz |   X
  30  joe |   X
  30  moh |   X
```

This is a human readable view of the hasmap: the key is actually packed with the above `pack` function. As you can see the key is the **composition** of the `age` and the `primarykey` of the the item stored previously. In this case the value is not used because we don't need it. Mind the fact that each key is and must be unique.

Once that schema in place, you do "select queries", called range queries in bsddb using [`Cursor.set_range(key)`](https://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb_doc/dbcursor.html#set_range). This will set the cursor at the nearest key and return the key/value pair associated (the semantic can be a bit different depending on the database).

For instance to retrieve the first person that has `age=30`, one use the following code:

```
def get_first_person_with_age_thirty()
    key, _ = age_index.set_range(pack(30))  # we don't need value
    age, pk = unpack(key)
    # set_range, will set the key to "30" and a pk
    # or with a key prefix superior to 30.
    #  So we need to check that age is really 30.
    if age == 30:
        return loads(users[pk])
```

This will return the document associated with user `amz`.

To go further one needs to make use of the other bsddb interface which entry point is `bsddb.db.DB` and `bsddb.db.DBEnv` ([documentation](https://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb_doc/)]. With this interface you can have several hashmap bound to the same transaction context even if it's not required to use transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You can save multiple values against single key in berkeley db by setting the duplicate flag

```
filename = '/path/to/berkeley/db/file'
fruitDB = db.DB()
fruitDB.set_flags(db.DB_DUP)
fruitDB.open(filename, None, db.DB_BTREE, db.DB_CREATE)
fruitDB.put(str(1), "Waqar")
fruitDB.put(str(1), "Umer")
fruitDB.put(str(2), "x")
fruitDB.put(str(2), "y")
fruitDB.put(str(4), "z")
fruitDB.put(str(5), "e")
```

But you cant retrieve all of them using 'Get' method of BDB you have to use cursor to retrieve items see [documentation](http://pybsddb.sourceforge.net/bsddb3.html) for this or you can retrieve all the items belongs to single key using

```
cursor = fruitDB.cursor()
cursor.set(str(1))
record = cursor.current()
listTup = []
while record:
    print record
    listTup.append(record)
    record = cursor.next_dup()
```

output will be

```
('1', 'Waqar')
('1', 'Umer')
```

This will return list of tuple having all the values belong to key '1'
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose opening the database everytime with `w` option, you are overwriting everytime & only storing the last entry. You should instead use `a`.

```
db = bsddb.hashopen("/home/neeraj/public_html/database/mydb.db","a")
```

Extract from the official Python manual -->

```
    open() returns a file object, and is most commonly used with two arguments:
    open(filename, mode).
```

> > > f = open('workfile', 'w')
> > >       The first argument is a string containing the filename. The second argument is another string containing a few characters describing the way in which the file will be used. mode can be 'r' when the file will only be read, 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is automatically added to the end.

Comment: can i write like this db = bsddb.hashopen("/home/neeraj/public_html/database/mydb.db","c") . will it overwrite ???

Comment: Also there is no "a" in case of i am using hashopen .It says u can only use r ,w, c, n

Comment: I suppose trying is your only option as I am not familiar with BDB much.

Comment: the `'w'` mode is fine since it means `read+write` *without* trunctation. It would have been a problem if the OP used `n` which *does* truncate at zero. The `'c'` mode is also fine, since it is identical to `'w'` but if the file doesn't exist it creates it.

Comment: ok. So in the Berkeley db when 'w' mode is written., it means it is not overwriting the data content which i am inserting

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is: do not use the BDB for such a case. For simple applications you can use the builtin [sqlite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) module that was first introduced in python 2.5.