# query values in leveldb database in nodejs

Tags: node.js, leveldb, levelup, leveldown

How could I query a levelDB database by values in nodejs? 
I have key: value pairs in my leveldb database and I want to search some values in it and find that key-value pair from that result. I am a beginner in leveldb.

```
{
    "key1" : {
                 "data1": "value1",
                 "data2": "value2",
                 "data3": "value3"
             }
}
```

So, I want to query value where data3 == value3 and get that key-value pair.

In levelDB, we can only get data on the basis of key.
Is there any other alternative?

Comment: I found one alternative to it by using levelgraph, in which we can search data using subject, predicate and object. But still if one have a object in any of these then searching those keys or values will be difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In leveldb, which a low level database abstraction you can "only" query by exact key match or prefix key range.

You can not query by value without somekind duplication.

What pattern I adopted in my graphdb project is to follow the [EAV model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) with a secondary "table" to store the index.

In Python plyvel you can emulate "table" using [prefixed databases](https://plyvel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user.html#prefixed-databases). Or see how FoundationDB does it in its Subspace implementation. Basically, every key-value pair of a given "table" or "space" is prefixed with a particular bytes sequence, that is all.

The first table, looks like the following:

```
(Entity, Attribute) → (Value)
```

Where `Entity` is a (random) identifier and `Attribute` is the byte representation of field name and last but not least `Value` is the bytes serialized value associated with `Attribute` for the given `Entity`.

The table schema is done that way so that you can quickly fetch using a range query all `Attribute` and `Value` using prefix range search over a given `Entity`.

The index table use the following schema:

```
(Attribute, Value) → Entity
```

That is it a shuffled version of the first table.

This is done like so, to make it possible to quickly fetch `Entity` that match a particular `Attribute == Value` that's what you are looking for.

There is alternative implementations for what you are looking for. Lookup my answers about [leveldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leveldb) and key-value stores e.g. [Expressing multiple columns in berkeley db in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399643/expressing-multiple-columns-in-berkeley-db-in-python/32148388#32148388)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By your explanation, I am able to create a small database but now I was thinking what if I have to query nested value. I am trying to create a blockchain type solution in nodejs.

Comment: I don't know blockchain. That said, if you want to create an `Entity` and use as `Value` of another entity. That way one entity contains another somewhat.